# This game is a puzzle in itself

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, music, video-games

> Although it can be scary,
>
> Everything ends alright.
>
> At least it did for me,
>
> But that might not be right.
>
> Choices make all the difference,
>
> Don't take any lightly.
>
> Everything changes how it ends,
>
> Abruptly or quite nicely.
>
> Be sure to check out all the paintings,
>
> Each one could fell even the mighty.

What am I?

Hint 1:

> Here's line 8 again.
>
> A<sup>b</sup>ruptly or quite nicely.

Hint 2:

> Remember

Comment: Should this be categorized as a riddle? If so, should it go to the Riddle Sandbox before posting on the main site? (It *looks* like a riddle, but I may be failing to understand how it works.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I believe that it is fine, as the method required to work out the answer is not related to the actual meaning/content of the text - hence the enigmatic tag :)

Comment: I notice that the first letters of each line are in the range [A..G] - all musical notes. It doesn't sound like a song to me, unfortunately.

Comment: @Deusovi You are on the right track, though it is not an entire song, not even an entire melody

Comment: @Deusovi [It's not Game of Thrones](/q/41667#comment123395_41670), but the reverse also sounds like part of something (EBAEDCBAEA).

Comment: @Deusovi Based on the hint, that A might be an Ab/G#...

Comment: I think what makes this really tricky is that the musical notes could be up or down from the previous one, so (as an example) there's no telling for sure if ABCDE is an ascending scale.

Comment: As of this posting, a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=AEABCDEABE) for `AEABCDEABE` returns only this puzzle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, So I'm 90% sure I know the answer, however I'm not the best to explain it as I only know the song and game from osu! and a walkthrough I watched once. So bear with me here.

Is it...

> Ib ?

Although it can be scary,

Everything ends alright.

At least it did for me,

But that might not be right.

> What this screams to me, is that this 'thing' is both a Horror game, with things that impact whether the ending will be a good one or a bad one. Ib fits that Mold.

Choices make all the difference,

Don't take any lightly.

Everything changes how it ends,

Abruptly or quite nicely.

> This fuels my first point some. Think about it, RPG maker games mainly focus around the user having to make choices that determine the outcome ([**Mogeko Castle**](http://mogeko-castle.wikia.com/wiki/Mogeko_Castle_Wiki:Mogeko_Castle_Wiki) is a fine example, A messed up, but fine example). As well as Ib. Some endings turn out good, some endings do not.
>  This could be a hint at the use of the keys AEABCDEABE (Thanks, DooplissForce. couldn't have got that without'ya) with some of the keys ending flat, or sharp. 
>  **Edit:** I forgot to mention, that the tune from the whole thing, sound a lot like a part of this tune here: **[Ib "Memory"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69Dix-v4h-I)**

Now onto my main reasoning for my thoughts to it being this!
Be sure to check out all the paintings,

Each one could fell even the mighty.

> PAINTINGS! paintings, paintings paintings paintings. 
>  What's one of Ib's underlying features? the use of paintings to fuel the storyline. For example The whole thing is held in an art gallery. A quote from the Wiki - *"A young girl named Ib visits an art gallery with her parents. While observing the many exhibits, she suddenly realizes she is alone. And in her search for others, she finds things awry in the gallery..."* 
>  The whole games premise is based around the paintings and defeating your enemies with the use of them, as well as other things in the game. 
>  In fact, two of the endings from the game are titled ***Forgotten Portrait*** as well as ***A Painting's Demise***

---

Any help toward my point would be great. If you have something I missed, please let me know in the comments.

Comment: Great job! And as an added note, the paintings also feature prominently as enemies, as well as sculptures - for example [Death of the Individual](http://ibgame.wikia.com/wiki/Death_of_the_Individual) (Yeah, those headless ones)

For the tick the song must also be identified!

Comment: I edited it to include that ^

Comment: Fantastic, well played ;)

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure this isn't right, but I have to mention it or I'll regret it if it's actually correct:

> **The Legend of Zelda: Ocarina of Time**
>  My reasoning is that the tune sounds somewhat like the main theme, where the first E note is low instead of high.
>  As for the text itself, it matches the title by way of the game being a puzzle game, and the reference to paintings being dangerous, one of the bosses of the game is Phantom Ganon who uses the paintings in a round room to hide and emerges from one to attack Link.

Comment: Wow I hadn't considered that the song is not only similar to the Zelda theme, but also that Phantom Ganon exists. This is a very good guess, but somehow further off than other guesses that have been made - at least the game itself is

Comment: Hopefully this means that the contour of the first seven notes matches that of the Legend of Zelda theme, because that would help narrow it down quite a bit.

Comment: Sadly I worded that badly :( Where I said "*Wow I hadn't considered that the song is not only similar to the Zelda theme*", the word similar can be taken to mean that it's not quite right, as this is a proper notation of the song in question

Comment: Are you familiar with the term "contour" where it's used to describe musicality?

Comment: Not even slightly haha

Comment: Care to explain?

Comment: Contour is used to describe when pitch goes up and down. When you start on a note (like E) and tell someone the next note is an A, you would not know whether you should go up to the higher A or down to the lower A. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah I see, in that case yes, the actual tune - for the most part - follows the same contour

Answer (score 1):

Is it maybe

> Game of Thrones? The first letter of each line can be interpreted as a music note, so we get AEABCDEABE, which when played sounds roughly like the music in the intro for Game of Thrones.

Comment: It is not game of thrones, the title is a clue and also the content of the poem pertains to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Its an

> Image puzzle
>
>  Might be like resident evil 4 painting puzzle

Comment: A good guess, but unless we can figure the music part out, it could be any other painting puzzle ever introduced in the history of video games (there are a ton of those).

Comment: Darn you, ffao. you have bested me in the race to spoilering this!
You win this time.

Also, yeah. Unless we figure out the music tag, we're as close to figuring this out as we are why our brains do what they do. We don't know yet.

Comment: No picture puzzles here, think genre

Comment: Well, actually the genre you have chosen is somewhat close...

Answer (score 1):

```
Although it can be scary,

Everything ends alright.

At least it did for me,

But that might not be right.
```

> A horror game with multiple endings. Silent Hill? There are Silent Hill games where the canonical ending is implied to be a bad ending, hence "might not be right"

```
Choices make all the difference,

Don't take any lightly.

Everything changes how it ends,

Abruptly or quite nicely.
```

> In Silent Hill games you determine the ending based on choices, especially Silent Hill Downpour with its more flexible morality system

```
Be sure to check out all the paintings,

Each one could fell even the mighty.
```

> Silent Hill Downpour had a painting puzzle where if you collected all of them and solved a puzzle you got some good stuff out of it. I don't know many horror games with multiple endings AND painting puzzles. I'm not sure about the melody, though. Are all notes in the same pitch? It seems faintly familiar to me, but that might just be because the sequence is so short.

Comment: This is on the right tracks, much of the reasoning is correct, but the paintings play a larger role. The melody may be more clear when using only the first 7 notes

Answer (score 0):

> Is it to do with X-Files? when i hum the notes at the starts of the each line it sounds a bit like the theme music.

Edit

> Is this the tell tale game of the walking dead? All of the choices that you make influence every part of the game there after and there are choices to make on every episode.

Comment: Unfortunately not, if you have a look at the other answers you may get a good hit though :)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be

> Layers of Fear? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layers_of_Fear 
>
>  It's a horror game, which features multiple endings based on the player's actions during the game. The game features a ton of paintings, and the theme song sorta sounds similar to the AEABCDEABE scheme.

Comment: Sadly this is incorrect, the notes really do sound exactly like what they mean to sound like